# Convert GroupedData in Spark to a list of pandas dataframes in pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

how can I transform a GroupedData object, that comes as a result of a groupBy on a spark dataframe, to a list of pandas dataframes?

```py
groups = df.groupby(["col1", "col2"])

list_of_pd_dfs = ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a list of unique combinations of pair `(col1, col2)` . Then filter the dataframe for each value in the list. Convert each filtered spark dataframe to pandas dataframe.